# Drf class based view how to manage method calls

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have been working on FBV in Django and am now trying out CBV. I have created a basic crud application

Views.py

```
class UserViews(APIView):
permission_classes = [IsViewOnly | IsManager | IsAdmin | IsStaff]

def get_objects(self, user_id):
    #query
def post(self, request):        
    #create code
def get(self, request):
    #details code
def put(self, request):
    #update code
def delete(self):
    #code
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('add-user/', views.UserViews.as_view(), name="create-user"),
path('update-user/', views.UserViews.as_view(), name="update-user"),
path('delete-user/', views.UserViews.as_view(), name="delete-user"),
path('list-users', views.UserSearchList.as_view(), name="list-user"),
path('view-user', views.UserViews.as_view(), name="view-user"),]
```

This code is working but, how do we prevent a situation where say a manager wants the view user details API but executes it with the delete method and the user is now deleted

Comment: There are many solutions to this problem. One of them can be return a warning response in this delete method and have a separate method for deleting the user. Or change the model's delete method so that when deleting, the user won't be deleted, but will be marked as deleted (an extra field).

Comment: @ruddra True but delete was just an example the main concern is an API called using the wrong HTTP method can be fatal unlike in fbv where the api_view decorator can prevent it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@api_view` decorator with function-based views, In order to set a specific permission on a specific method in the APIView class.

```
@permission_classes([IsManager, ])
def delete(self, request):
    # your code.
```

**Note**: when you set new permission classes via the class attribute or decorators you're telling the view to ignore the default list set in the `settings.py` file.
reference: [Django setting the permission policy](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy)

Comment: But i am using class-based views

Comment: No problem, just overwrite each function in the class with your specific permissions or let it without the `@action` decorator then it will get the default permissions from the class.

Comment: The permissions is not exactly the issue. In fbv API is calls only a specific function even if I call it with the wrong method it will give an error like GET method not allowed because of @api_view but in CBV all api for user crud call on the same class. so if an admin has all permission there is a likelihood that because of wrong method the  correct operation was not executed

Comment: You can remove all URLs and let only one, but you have to make sure about the method that you are calling (GET, POST, PATCH, and DELETE) when you call your endpoint.